# Nullpointer exception in Android broadcastreceiver onReceive() method

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am developing notification application using third party (Pushbots) API, almost I have completed my application. I can able to receive notification from third party API. I have divided my application users as two types, one is ITTI and second one is EXTERNAL users.

If I logged in my app as ITTI users mean its working fine. If I logged in as a EXTERNAL user mean, I can able to receive notification in status bar from third party `API`, but the problem is if click the notification on the status bar to load in EXTERNAL user main activity page, it throws `NullPointerException`. But for ITTI users, I can receive and also I can open `ITTI` users main activity page.

For receiving the notification I used `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive()` method. My guess is null exception in `intent` of `onReceive()` method, the following are the code which receives notification using BroadcastReceiver:

```
**ReceiverClass.java**


package com.example.itti_integration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import com.example.external.External;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class CustomPushReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String TAG = "customPushReceiver";
    private static final String MODE_PRIVATE = null;
    SharedPreferences Notify_Pref;

    String mm1, mm2;
    String mm;
    String Extmsg;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent in) {
        //String msg = null, qry = null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{

        String action = in.getAction();
        System.out.println(action+ " intent action");
        Log.d(TAG, "action=" + action);
        String itti_alias = null;
       String alias= System.getProperty("alias", itti_alias);
       String ealias = null;
       String external =    System.getProperty("extAlias", ealias);
System.out.println(alias + "ealias "+ external);

if(alias.equals("itti"))
{

        // Handle Push Message when opened
       if (action.equals(Pushbots.MSG_OPENED)) {

            HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) in.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_OPEN);

            Log.w(TAG, "User clicked notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message") );

          mm1=PushdataOpen.get("message").toString();

            if(!LoadMsg.isActive() )

            {

                HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen1 = (HashMap<?, ?>) in.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE);
                Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                launch.setClass(Pushbots.getInstance().appContext, LoadMsg.class);
                launch.putExtra("message", mm1);
                launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                Pushbots.getInstance().appContext.startActivity(launch);

            }


        // Handle Push Message when received
        }
       else if(action.equals(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE))
       {
            HashMap<?, ?> Pushdata = (HashMap<?, ?>)  in.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE);
            Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + Pushdata.get("message"));

            mm=Pushdata.get("message").toString();

            System.setProperty("mm", mm);

        }

    }

else


     // Handle Push Message when opened
    if (action.equals(Pushbots.MSG_OPENED)) {

         HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen = (HashMap<?, ?>) in.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_OPEN);

         Log.w(TAG, "User clicked notification with Message: " + PushdataOpen.get("message") );

       mm2=PushdataOpen.get("message").toString();

       System.setProperty("emsg", mm2);

         if(!External.isActive() ){

              HashMap<?, ?> PushdataOpen1 = (HashMap<?, ?>) in.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE);

             Intent launch1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             launch1.setClass(Pushbots.getInstance().appContext, External.class);
             //launch.putExtra("message", mm1);
             launch1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

             Pushbots.getInstance().appContext.startActivity(launch1);

         }

     // Handle Push Message when received
     }
    else if(action.equals(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE)){
         HashMap<?, ?> Pushdata = (HashMap<?, ?>)  in.getExtras().get(Pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE);
         Log.w(TAG, "User Received notification with Message: " + Pushdata.get("message"));
         mm1=Pushdata.get("message").toString();

         System.setProperty("mm1", mm1);

     }


    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.toString());

    }

    }

    }
```

This is the class which I'm using to receive notification and making pageload as per the users category, really I stuck in this point, I don't know why am getting Null exception.

**This is my Logcat out:**

```
08-04 17:16:36.002: W/System.err(2913): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 17:16:36.002: W/System.err(2913):     at com.example.itti_integration.CustomPushReceiver.onReceive(CustomPushReceiver.java:58)
08-04 17:16:36.014: W/System.err(2913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
08-04 17:16:36.032: W/System.err(2913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-04 17:16:36.052: W/System.err(2913):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
08-04 17:16:36.062: W/System.err(2913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 17:16:36.072: W/System.err(2913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-04 17:16:36.072: W/System.err(2913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 17:16:36.072: W/System.err(2913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 17:16:36.072: W/System.err(2913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-04 17:16:36.072: W/System.err(2913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-04 17:16:36.222: W/System.err(2913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 17:16:36.242: I/System.out(2913): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Still I couldn't figureout where I am wrong. Pls  anyone suggest me the solution....

Comment: Post your logcat output up to and including the crash

Comment: which line of code from above code is line 58

Comment: if(!LoadMsg.isActive) is the line no 58